# Post an image to facebook album from a url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

Is there a possibility that we can specify a url instead of realpath of the image that we want to upload on facebook

for instance to upload an image on facebook we make use of this code in php

```
 $args = array(
  'message' => 'Message',
  'image'   => '@' . realpath($path_to_image),
```

in the image parameter can we specify a url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a URL instead of realpath. See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/